# What pinyin combinations spell out English words?

Tags: pinyin

I’m always impressed when I see a good combination of pinyin that spells out an English word.

I’ve see companies with names similar to:

- 立刻(出行) li + ke = like

People with names like:

- an + na = Anna

And combinations like:

- shi + te

Confusing the unsuspecting Brits.

What other combinations of pinyin spell out English words or names?

---

Edit: Also saw something like 爬竿 the other day written as: PAGAN, threw me off for a min.

Comment: I heard a joke that said: "The two Chinese pilots of the crashed airplane were 'Wii Too Lo' and 'Ho Li Xit' . It is like English speakers make fun of Chinese language.

Comment: A similar joke: Originally, 香蕉 had no English name, English people just knew it was a kind of fruit from Africa. Until one day, an Englishman  pointed at a Cantonese guy who was eating 香蕉 and said:" The Chinese would eat anything, even that yellow fruit from Africa which only monkeys would eat. How stupid!"  unfortunately for him, that Cantonese man understood what he said, angrily beat him over the head with 香蕉, and yelled " 笨吖嗱！笨吖嗱！" and that's how 香蕉 became known as " banana"(笨吖嗱 ) in English.

Comment: "何诗婷" = "he shi-ting"

Comment: @WDC good one. I also found that 石亭之战 is translated as the **Battle of Shiting** after you mentioned the other one.

Comment: 我们 - lots of English-speakers on looking at Pinyin transcriptions remark on that as the most common "recognised" word!

Comment: Theoretically one could write a more comprehensive answer by 1) list all valid pinyin for chinese words, 2) compare it to an English dictionary and 3) sort the list by its giggle factor.  I'm not sure how to approach this, though.

Comment: I get confused with signs that say "Side road" in China.  It takes me a while to realize it's not a road named Sīdé.

Comment: Anyone want some sushi ([素食](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=素食) [sùshí] = vegetarian food)?

Comment: There are probably thousands of these, all someone needs to do is to run a comparison between an English dictionary and a Chinese one, in Pinyin, stripping tones. I don't really see the point, to be honest. It's somewhat interesting when the meanings are related, but arbitrary coincidences in words? Not so much.

Comment: Not English, but 綠茶 is written almost like "lucha" (fight) in Spanish. Spelled with a V it gets a Roman feel as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the character 娥 (u+5a25) is a common name in canton, so:

change --> chang + e 嫦娥

june --> jun + e 俊娥

die --> di + e 娣娥

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

what about this one,an simple chinese female first name 诗婷 shi ting